# Flutter AnimatedContainer Can u Help Me?

Tags: flutter, frontend

When i tap menu icon i want to my main container swipe left and menu looks like android mobile-2

when i click my menu button nothing changed and i got this error Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

i cant figure out

Here my codes:

YanMenu widget just container with color

```
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xff3F48C1),
  // --------- Bottom Navigation Bar BAŞLANGIÇ ------------
  bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavBar(),
  // --------- Bottom Navigation Bar BİTİŞ ------------
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      YanMenu(),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        color: Color(0xff3F48C1),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 32, 10, 20),
        child:    !isDrawerOpen
                      ? IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              xOffSet = 0;
                              yOffSet = 0;
                              scaleFactor = 1;
                              isDrawerOpen = false;
                            });
                          })
                      : IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            OrdUpIcons.carpi,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              xOffSet = 230;
                              yOffSet = 150;
                              scaleFactor = 0.6;
                              isDrawerOpen = true;
                            });
                          })
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Flexible(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffSet, yOffSet, 0)
              ..scale(scaleFactor),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!isDrawerOpen
                      ? IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.menu,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 30,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              xOffSet = -(genislik / 2);
                              yOffSet = 0;
                              scaleFactor = 1;
                              isDrawerOpen = true;
                              left = 20;
                              right = 30;
                              _borderRadius = BorderRadius.only(
                                topRight: Radius.circular(45),
                              );
                            });
                          })
                      : IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            OrdUpIcons.carpi,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 20,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              xOffSet = 0;
                              yOffSet = 0;
                              scaleFactor = 1;
                              isDrawerOpen = false;
                              left=30;
                              right=20;
                              _borderRadius = BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
                              );
                            });
                          })
```

I changed the container under YanMenu like this and my problem is solved